# Why my div is not aligning to middle vertically?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I don't know how to ask this...

I made a layout using some css, I have a container div (.truck_info) with 2 elements inside, the first one is on the top, and the second one (.truck_cont) has a height:100% and vertical-align:middle (it covers the whole container), I don't know why the elements inside this second element are not aligned to middle, this is my code:

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5qtbkemy/

HTML code:

```
<div class="truck_slot" >
<table class="table_truck"><tbody><tr>
<td class="truck_colo" style="background-color:#F11; ">
  <div class="truck_time">Left pane</div>
</td>
<td class="truck_info">
  <div class="truck_stop" style="background-color:#F11; ">Top line</div>
  <div class="truck_cont"> 
    <div class="truck_name" style="font-size:28px; ">Middle</div>
    <div class="truck_para" style="font-size:11px;">Why this text isn't</div>
    <div>middle align?</div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.truck_slot{
    float:left;
    width:170px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:5px 8px;
}
.table_truck{
    width:100%;
    height: 155px;
    padding:0px;
    border:1px #CCCCCC solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:2px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}
.table_truck td{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
}
.table_truck .truck_colo{
    height:100%;
    width: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.table_truck .truck_time{
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: "Calibri", "Century Gothic", Century, Arial, "Arial Black";
}
.table_truck .truck_info{
    height:100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    color:#666;
}
.table_truck .truck_info .truck_info_div{
    height:90px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.table_truck .truck_stop{
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.table_truck .truck_cont{
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.table_truck .truck_name{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 0 14px 0 3px;
    /*margin-bottom:10px*/
}
.table_truck .truck_para{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:3px;
}
```

I hope you can help me to understand what is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you interested in flexbox solution ? Let me know if you are, so I can post it as answer.

Comment: try this : https://jsfiddle.net/5qtbkemy/2/

Comment: Here is the flexbox solution http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNjQKK

Comment: @Belmin, it's looks good, but I don't understand how it works, and how to use it in my <table>, can you try editing my example?

Comment: The common issue in CSS was always pefectly align element.With flexbox is't just a joke, so I get rid of all old hacks about centering and switched to flexbox - and trust me, flexbox is the best thing about CSS ever :)

Comment: Yes. But before you change everything if you need to support IE don't use flexbox

Comment: ok, I learned something about flex-box and it worked!! thank you

Comment: Have you tried putting the 'middle align?' text inside a p tag?

Comment: Also, you can add position: relative and min-height: calc(100% - 20px) to your truck_cont class. The -20px is to compensate for the stop line-height

Comment: That is a good idea, I forgot about calc, thank you, the flex-box solution worked very good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct original answer was deleted by the author, what I used was a flex-box solution, I added 3 lines:

```
.table_truck .truck_cont{
    height: 85%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: flex; /* To use flexbox I need to set a flex display */
    flex-direction: column; /* to make it vertical I change the direction to column */
    justify-content: center; /* finally, I must set the orientation to center */
}
```

This is the edited jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5qtbkemy/5/

I found this link useful to learn quickly about flex-box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center` and remove the `padding` on `.truck_name`.

`.truck_para` needs a `text-align: center` too, as does the div below it.

```css
.truck_slot{
 float:left;
 width:170px;
 cursor:pointer;
 margin:5px 8px;
}
.table_truck{
 width:100%;
 height: 155px;
 padding:0px;
 border:1px #CCCCCC solid;
 border-radius:10px;
 padding:2px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}
.table_truck td{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #666;
}
.table_truck .truck_colo{
 height:100%;
 width: 55px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
 border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
 color: #FFF;
}
.table_truck .truck_time{
 font-size:13px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family: "Calibri", "Century Gothic", Century, Arial, "Arial Black";
}
.table_truck .truck_info{
 height:100%;
 vertical-align: top;
 color:#666;
}
.table_truck .truck_info .truck_info_div{
 height:90px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.table_truck .truck_stop{
 border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
 padding: 0 5px;
 color: #FFF;
 line-height:20px;
 font-size:13px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.table_truck .truck_cont{
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.table_truck .truck_name{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding: 0;
 /*margin-bottom:10px*/
  text-align: center;
}
.table_truck .truck_para{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-left:3px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="truck_slot" >
<table class="table_truck"><tbody><tr>
<td class="truck_colo" style="background-color:#F11; ">
  <div class="truck_time">Left pane</div>
</td>
<td class="truck_info">
  <div class="truck_stop" style="background-color:#F11; ">Top line</div>
  <div class="truck_cont"> 
    <div class="truck_name" style="font-size:28px; ">Middle</div>
    <div class="truck_para" style="font-size:11px;">Why this text isn't</div>
    <div style="text-align: center">middle align?</div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: what about vertical alignment? I going to edit the question title.

Comment: Ok. I didn't add vertical alignment, pretty sure it'd work though.

Answer (score -2):

I often use the line-height to height div element in which vertically centered text:

`div {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;}`

Comment: Thank you, sadly this doesn't work if text has more than 1 line